# sml function that take in BST datatype and return a list in order

Tags: sml

I have function for BST that insert numbers in that looks like this

val t = Node (Node (Empty,10,Empty),20,Node (Empty,30,Empty)) : BST

How do I write a function that takes in val t and return a list of the order in BST like [10,20,30]

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use the *inorder* tree traversal algorithm. It starts at the root node, processes the left subtree, then process the the current node and finally process the right subtree.

But in this special case the standard left-to-right inorder traversal is very inefficient since it would make use of list's append operation which is O(n).

To be able to use list's prepend operation (which is constant time O(c)) you better process the right subtree first, then process current nodes value and finally continue to process the left subtree. You are basically folding the tree from right to left. Therefore you could define a simple helper function *foldr*:

```
fun foldr f a Empty = a
  | foldr f a (Node (left, n, right)) = foldr f (f (n, foldr f a right)) left
```

and use it  to define a **toList** function:

```
val toList = foldr (op ::) []
```